# C# и .Net. Почему пользовательская функция Swap работает неправильно?

Tags: c#, массивы, .net

Добрый вечер!

Задача следующая: Дан так называемый ступенчатый(зубчатый) массив целых чисел
 `int[][] matrix`. Для определенности, пусть массив будет размерности 5:

```
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][]
    {   
        new int[10] {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5},
        new int[4] {2, 2, 2, 2},
        new int[5] {20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        new int[3] {1, 2, 1},
        new int[4] { 2, 3, 4, 5 }
    }
```

Необходимо поменять две любые строки между собой. Для этого я написал следующую функцию `Swap`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Swapping matrix strings
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">first string</param>
    /// <param name="b">second string</param>
    private static void SwapMatrixStrings(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int[] tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
```

Казалось бы, что переменные типа `int[]` - это переменные ссылочного типа. Но почему тогда после вызова:

```
    Swap(matrix[0], matrix[1]);
```

массив `int[4] {2, 2, 2, 2}` не поменялся местами с массивом `int[10] {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}` в массиве `matrix`?

**UPD.** Если в методе передавать параметры по ссылке с помощью ключевого слова `ref`, то метод работает так, как надо.

Comment: потому что вы по сути поменяли локальные ссылки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что она обменивает локальные переменные, а не параметры.
Параметры в C# передаются по значению, если не указано `ref` или `out`. Это относится и к параметрам ссылочного типа, при этом по значению передаётся *ссылка*.

Попробуйте указать в сигнатуре функции `ref`.

---

Что происходит в вашем коде? В функцию `SwapMatrixStrings` вы передали ссылочные выражения `matrix[0]` и `matrix[1]` в качестве аргументов. То есть, параметры `a` и `b` получили значение, совпадающее с `matrix[0]` и `matrix[1]` (то есть, их *копии*).

В результате выполнения вашей функции, значения `a` и `b` поменялись местами. Но это никак не затрагивает исходные величины `matrix[0]` и `matrix[1]`.

Comment: Кажется, я понял: я поменял адреса ссылок, но т.к. ссылки передаются по значению, то после выхода из функции значения ссылок остаются неизменными. Спасибо!

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Совершенно верно: _ссылки_ передаются тоже _по значению_.

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал, что мне придется передавать когда-нибудь ссылку по ссылке :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Ага, передача ссылки по ссылке звучит странно. :)

Comment: @VladD самая обычная косвенная адресация =) В C# всего то три возможных типа адресации. Но я понимаю что в асм заглядывают сейчас очень не многие, там их от 5-и, в зависимости от архитектуры проца. Иногда этого не хватает и в ЯВУ, правда редко, поэтому жить можно =)

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, любой указатель по сути косвенная адресация, да.

Comment: @VladD не, не любой. Именно ref или out параметр ссылочного типа  "косвенная адресация", для ValueType в аналогичной ситуации будет "прямая адресация", которая по умолчанию для всех ссылочных типов. Для ValueType по умолчанию - непосредственная. Прямая - подразумевает что параметр содержит ссылку на объект, непосредственная - содержит сам объект, косвенная - содержит ссылку на ссылку на объект

Comment: @rdorn: Ну так ValueType же обслуживается не аналогом указателя?

Comment: В случае с ref или out, как раз аналогом

Comment: @rdorn: Угу, ref — один уровень косвенности, ссылка — второй.